MCP (Personalization) SDK / sitemap which namespace to use and how to configure sitemap for multiple domains

In MCP (Personalization) SDK / sitemap, when we are reviewing the namespace, examples are supporting both: SalesforceInteractions & Evergage
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/personalization/guide/multisite-implementation-strategy.html?q=multi+sit

which namespace should be used for constructing sitemap and what are the key differences?

If we want to integrate company site and cloud pages within SFMC, is there any need to define multiple datasets? another user case is staging site and production site, any best practices - one default dataset (engage) or multiple datasets?

It is recommended to create sitemap for multiple domains? are there any examples how sitemap code looks like for multiple sites (domains)?

If we are integrating our staging site with MCP, should we consider creating a separate dataset?


As per this doc, after we create a dataset, it can't be deleted:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/personalization/guide/web-integration-planning.html
But, as per this help doc, dataset can be deleted:
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_pers_datasets_delete.htm&language=en_US&type=5
which is true?
